# react-loadable enabled compoent not receiving new props when sent from parent

Tags: reactjs, react-loadable

I have a component that i'm loading via react-loadable. The component that is being loading has some logic in componentWillReceiveProps for detecting if it needs to get some more data, etc.

When loaded via react loadable, it calls render 1 time, and componentWillReceiveProps is never called.

```
import React from 'react'
import Loadable from 'react-loadable'

import Loading from 'components/Loading'

const LoadableThing = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('components/Thing'),
  loading: Loading,
  render(loaded, props) {
    let Component = loaded.default;
    return <Component {...props}/>
  }
});

export default LoadableThing
```

And this component is included in another component that's making some initial data calls and sending the results to the `Thing`

any thoughts?  It's calling `return <Component` again, but that seems like it's creating a new component in that case.